# Using sed in makefile

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use sed in makefile as shown below. But it doesn't seem to produce the modified file. I have tried the sed command in the shell and made sure it works.

```
ana:
    -for ana1 in $(anas) ; do \
        for ana2 in $(anas) ; do \
            sed "s/STF1/$$ana1/g" ./planalysis/src/analysis.arr > ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr ; \
            sed "s/STF2/$$ana2/g" ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr > ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr ; \
            # ... perform some analysis with the modified file..
            # ...
        done \
    done
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think that make may not be the tool to use for this. Make is used to describe how to convert a file or files into an output file.  The ana: output is not clearly tied to any input files. A simple bash script should work just fine for this. If you want to involve make to tell when to run the bash script then do so, but don't mangle make to do looping logic. Make should read like this:   ana depends on x y and y.  There is how you take x y and z and make ana from them.

Comment: You can merge two sed command in one: `sed -e "s/STF1/$$ana1/g" -e "s/STF2/$$ana2/g" ./planalysis/src/analysis.arr > ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr`. This will improve performance and resolve issue with overwriting input stream in your second `sed` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command won't do whst you expect:

```
sed "s/STF2/$$ana2/g" ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr > ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr ;
```

regardless of whether you execute it in a Makefile or in your shell.

If you execute

```
some-command my.file > my.file
```

You are likely to end up with an empty `my.file`, regardless of the command, because redirections are set up before the command executes. As soon as the shell does the redirection `> my.file`, that file is emptied, because that's  what output redirection does. When the command eventually executes and attempts to read `my.file`, it will find thar the file is empty. In the case of sed, and many other commands, an empty input produces an empty output, and I suppse that is what you are seeing.

Use a temporary file, or use `sed -i` (see `man sed`) or, as suggested by [@AlexeySemenyuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4224163/alexey-semenyuk) in a comment, combine the edits into a single sed invocation:

```
sed -e "s/STF1/$$ana1/g" -e "s/STF2/$$ana2/g" \
    ./planalysis/src/analysis.arr > ./planalysis/src/spanalysis.arr
```